# Is it possible to broadcast a dictionary and use it as a lookup in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm running the below code in azure databricks.

1. Creating a lookup dictionary using erp_bu which is a list of row objects having two columns, 'erp_code' and 'bu'
2. Broadcasting the lookup dictionary
3. Trying to lookup values in a udf

Is there another way to do this if this is not correct?
I'm getting an error that Broadcast variable is not loaded. I tried passing the broadcast variable to the udf but it only accepts strings or columns.

````
erp_bu_dic = {}
for row in erp_bu:
    if row['erp_code']:
        erp_bu_dic[row['erp_code']] = row['bu']
broadcast_erp_bu_dic = sc.broadcast(erp_bu_dic)
j06 = j06.withColumn('business_unit', udf(lambda x : broadcast_erp_bu_dic.value[x])("entity_source_id"))
display(j06)```
````

Answer (score 1):

In principle your approach should work, and the **answer is yes, it is possible to broadcast a dictionary and use it as a lookup**.

It's difficult to identify what your issue is without more detail, but I tried to mock-up a scenario as close as possible to your description, and the below code runs fine.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import Row

#mock the j06 dataframe        
j06_data = [("1YZ", "meh"), ("X2Z", "blah"), ("XY3", "ha")] 
df_j06 = spark.createDataFrame(j06_data, ["entity_source_id", "other_col"]) 

#mock the business unit dictionary
bu_rows = [Row(erp_code="1YZ", bu="BU One"), Row(erp_code="X2Z", bu="BU Two"), Row(erp_code="XY3", bu="BU Three")]
erp_bu_dict = {}
for row in bu_rows:
    erp_bu_dict[row['erp_code']] = row['bu']

#broadcast the dict
broadcast_bu_dict = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(erp_bu_dict)

#define mapping udf
udf_map_bu = udf(lambda x : broadcast_bu_dict.value[x])
#map business unit
df_j06 = df_j06.withColumn('business_unit', udf_map_bu('entity_source_id'))

display(df_j06)
```

I'd speculate that the issue is earlier in your code and related to your "erp_bu" list of rows.

I would also **consider converting "erp_bu" to a dataframe and run a join** instead of your current approach.

Comment: Hey @Wietla, I copied your code and it gave me the following error.

SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 144.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 144.0 (TID 232) (10.139.64.12 executor 0): com.databricks.spark.safespark.UDFException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: [BROADCAST_VARIABLE_NOT_LOADED] Broadcast variable `113` not loaded.

This might have to do with some settinng on my setup.

Additionally why would it be better to use joins instead of this?

Comment: Hi @PaawanAngra, that's very strange. What Apache Spark and Python versions are you using? I'm running this on Apache Spark 3.3 and Python 3.10.
Also, using a join should be more efficient and robust as you don't need to broadcast the business unit lookup dataframe. In your current dictionary approach if the mapping is not available in the dict then your code will crash. If you use a left join then when the mapping is not available the value will simply be null and the code will run fine.